# Copy not null and not empty fields from one object to another object of the same type(Objects are same type) in java

Tags: java, hibernate, struts

I am using hibernate, struts, extjs in my project.

I have a Customer object with these fields:

> custId,
>   custName, 
>   address, 
>   phone

and in my project from UI side I get an object customer with `custName`.

So I need to update the above object(`custName` is unique). I have only one object with the same customer name. So I will get that object using customer name (object from DB).

Now I have to save the object with the updated customer name.

If I save as follows I have Customer Object from UI, is cust

> Customer cust1 = getCustomerByName(cust.getCustName());
>
> cust.setCustId(cust1.getCustId()); save(cust);

If I do this I lose the customer address and phone number.

So, how can I copy one object not null or not empty field values to another object of same type.

Can any one please help. I just stuck here. It's stopping me to save.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A curious data model where CustomerName would be unique and CustomerId would be updated.

Comment: @radimpe Using customer Id as internal purpose but my customer name is unique in my case.And not the problem with uniquenes i just gave the example of data model its not rea. But how to copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options. Use reflection to find all fields and copy the ones that are not null. Or better option, write an update method that explicitly checks each field and updates the database instance's fields as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up your references to `cust` and `cust1`.

Unless `cust` already had an address, no amount of setting JUST the `custId` on `cust` would also copy the address from `cust1`.

Comment: I have to check every time is customer name is null or address is null. Here data model has less fields. In my case it has so many. I cant check every thing so i want to copy only not null and not empty fields. until and unless i wont copy the old values are lost.

Comment: @Chinni - but unless you check, how would you know if a value is null or not... Sometimes, you just gotta suck it up and crank out those `if` statements.

Comment: This is a case where there is a trade-off for reflection. Reflection has a runtime efficiency cost but can set any number of fields with a minimal amount of code.

Comment: write a script that generate the code for you and use the if instead of the reflection...